# Unexpected end of JSON input for 'SELECT *' php query

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax

I have the following php function that selects title, x_coordinates, y_coordinates, opening_hours and closing hours. When I call this function with ajax it retrieves them without error. However when I change my query to 'SELECT *' then I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse() at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload. I don't understand what the problem might be. Thanks for the help.

```
function getCoordinates($title) {
    $db = connect();

    $query = 'SELECT title, x_coordinates, y_coordinates, opening_hours, closing_hours FROM places WHERE title = :title';

    $getCoordinates = $db->prepare($query);

    $getCoordinates->execute(array(
        ':title'=>$title
    ));

    if($getCoordinates) {
        return $getCoordinates->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
function searchLocation() {
    var locationTitle = document.getElementById('search-title').value;
    locationTitle = locationTitle.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]/g, '');

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'db/get_coordinates.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    request.onload = function() {
        if(request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            var data = request.responseText;
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
    request.send('locationTitle='+locationTitle);
}
```

Also here is the get_coordinates.php

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';

$locationTitle = $_POST['locationTitle'];

$getCoordinates = getCoordinates($locationTitle);

if($getCoordinates) {
    echo json_encode($getCoordinates);
}
```

Comment: the json returned by the server would be helpful (not the expected one, but the actual one).

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. We have no way to run your code and see where it stops producing the correct output. If you don't have a debugger you can always [print variables](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: Sounds like it is a syntax error. Make sure you have a space after the `*`. `SELECT * FROM places WHERE title = :title `